# set child element to be 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a main element which is divided into a grid of 3 columns.
in the middle column I am displaying some listings.
each listing is a div element and has a react bootstrap card inside it.

I am trying to get the card to span 100% of the parent but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

React component

```
        <div className="backfill"> 
            <Row key={Listing_Id}>
                <Card style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}  border="light" className="text-center fullCard" >
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title className="Title">
                            {Listing_Name}
                            <hr />
                            <Button className="Button" variant="outline-success" onClick={() => props.handleLikeDisLike(Listing_Id, 'Listing_Likes', Listing_Location)}> <Twemoji options={options} text=":+1:" /></Button>
                            <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{Listing_Likes}</Badge>
                            <Button className="Button" variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => props.handleLikeDisLike(Listing_Id, 'Listing_DisLikes', Listing_Location)}><Twemoji options={options} text=":-1:" /></Button>
                            <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{Listing_DisLikes}</Badge>
                            <hr />
                            <Button className="Button" variant="outline-info" ><Twemoji text=":pushpin:" /></Button>
                            <Badge className="Badge" variant="light">{Listing_Location}</Badge>
                        </Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text className="Listing" onClick={() => handleClick(Listing_Id)} >
                            <hr />
                            {ListingBody}
                            <ModalLayout
                                Listing_Location={Listing_Location}
                                Listing_Likes={Listing_Likes}
                                Listing_DisLikes={Listing_DisLikes}
                                Listing_Name={Listing_Name}
                                Listing_Id={Listing_Id}
                                handleLikeDisLike={props.handleLikeDisLike}
                                handleClose={closeModal}
                                show={showModal} />

                        </Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Row>
            <br />
        </div >
```

CSS for div and Card elements

```
.backfill {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.fullCard {
    width:'100%';
}
```

I currently end up with the UI looking like this. Please can you help me sort this out. I want to get the card to be 100% of its parent div.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to remove the single quotes from the CSS

```
.fullCard {
    width:'100%';
}
```

had to become

```
.fullCard {
    width:100%;
}
```